# Как правильно организовать модели в связке MongoDB\Tornado и какой шаблонизатор лучше выбрать?

Tags: python, mongodb, шаблонизаторы

Перед нашей командой поставили задачу сделать большой, масштабируемый проект.Проект решили делать на [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/)+[MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Python+Language+Center). Для работы с MongoDB используем [mongolite](https://github.com/namlook/MongoLite) который ставится поверх [pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/). Если примерно, то суть проекта такая : кто-то создает набор форм  для заполнения данных и назначает их определенным группам юзеров. Юзер заполняет форму и сохраняет ее. Дальше третьему типу юзеров, показывается статистика, которая собирается из данных связанных с каждой формой.

Некоторые сценарии работы и модели, могут менятся в течении реализации. поэтому еще одной из задач, которые мы перед собой ставим, является использовать гибкие решения.

Для начала решили сделать внутренний api.
Сейчас у нас примерно так выглядит решение:

- описывается модель, в ней статические методы для создания сущностей, и внутр. методы для того,чтобы отдать инфу по объекту
- в метод api всегда передается user, который проверяется декоратором на наличие прав вызывать этот объект
- если все ок, то там выполняется какая-то логика, например вызывается статич. метод какого-нибудь класса который создает нужный объект и он возвращается данной api-функцией
- в обратотчиках url'oв (в основном в get-ах и постах) уже используются необходимые api-функции при реализации бизнес-логики
- Рендрится необходимая страница

Какой шаблонизатор лучше взять?
В первом релизе упора на [GUI](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F) не будет, однако в следующем релизе, такую задачу скорее всего перед нами поставят.

Интересно было бы узнать про чужой опыт разработки в этой связке.

Comment: @stasych, для поиска людей в свою команду воспользуйтесь [Карьерой](http://careers.hashcode.ru/).

Comment: вопрос не про команду. про команду я просто написал до кучи) я думаю, что это уберут модераторы)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-за шаблонизатор?

Что бы хотите шаблонизировать?

Чем вам стандартный, торнадовский шаблонизатор не угодил?   (http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/template.html)

[сравнение шаблонизаторов](http://code.google.com/p/spitfire/source/browse/trunk/tests/perf/bigtable.py).

```
Python 2.6.2 on a 3GHz Intel Core 2

Kid template                         696.89 ms
Kid template + cElementTree          649.88 ms
Genshi template + tag builder        431.01 ms
Genshi tag builder                   389.39 ms
Django template                      352.68 ms
Genshi template                      266.35 ms
ElementTree                          180.06 ms
cElementTree                         107.85 ms
StringIO                              41.48 ms
Jinja 2                               36.38 ms
Cheetah template                      34.66 ms
Mako Template                         29.06 ms
Spitfire template                     21.80 ms
Tenjin                                18.39 ms
Spitfire template -O1                 11.86 ms
cStringIO                              5.80 ms
Spitfire template -O3                  4.91 ms
Spitfire template -O2                  4.82 ms
generator concat                       4.06 ms
list concat                            3.99 ms
generator concat optimized             2.84 ms
list concat optimized                  2.62 ms
```